# Combine data across multiple sheets while keeping columns but ignoring blanks

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have three sheets in a workbook where people enter data (text values) in different columns, with different row lengths.

For example:

**Sheet 1**

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Apple | Apple |
| Orange | Orange | Banana |
|  | Banana | Peach |
|  | Pear |  |

**Sheet 2**

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Onion | Onion | Onion |
| Tomato | Tomato | Leek |
| Leek |  | Garlic |
|  |  | Potato |

I'm looking to combine this data into a single sheet, displayed as such:

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Apple | Apple |
| Orange | Orange | Banana |
| Onion | Banana | Peach |
| Tomato | Pear | Onion |
| Leek | Onion | Leek |
|  | Tomato | Garlic |
|  |  | Potato |

I've tried this formula:

`=QUERY({Sheet1!A3:G;Sheet2!A3:G;Sheet3!A3:G},"select * where Col1<>'' or Col2<>'' or Col3<>''",0)`

But it adds in blanks for as many as the longest column is on each sheet, like so:

| Group 1 |
| --- |
| Apple |
| Orange |
|  |
|  |
| Onion |
| Tomato |
| Leek |

Is there anything I can change to have it just list the items per column in the order queried, skipping blank cells as opposed to rows? I found lots of guidance in other questions about consolidating into a single column, but I want to keep the columns separated and consolidate rows instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use multiple queries, one for each column. Even after that, we can't stack the arrays horizontally using `{,}` because arrays are jagged([jagged-arrays](/questions/tagged/jagged-arrays)). We can use `SORT` each column to  give a appearance of removing blanks, as blanks are sorted to the bottom. Then stack them back. To automate this process, we can use `REDUCE` to loop:

```
=REDUCE(
  ,
  SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A:C)),
  LAMBDA(a,c,
    LAMBDA(
      s,
      IF(a="",s,{a,s})
    )(SORT(INDEX({Sheet1!A2:C;Sheet2!A2:C},0,c)))
  )
)
```

This removes the original order though

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 IF({Sheet1!A2:C; Sheet2!A2:C}="",,"​"&{Sheet1!A2:C; Sheet2!A2:C}),,9^9)), "​")))
```

[image]